# Doubts about a Turing Machine Problem

Tags: turing-machines, automata

The following is an excerpt from the book *"Introduction to the theory of Computation"* by Michael Sipser, 2nd edition.
[image]

As per the book, this Turing machine accepts the language **L = { w#w | w ∈{0, 1}*}**. I ran this machine for few strings and it's working properly.

My doubt is, I think there is no need of keeping a transition on the state q6 for 0 and 1.

I mean, if the transition on state q6 was **x -> L in place of 0,1,x->L**  then also this machine will work properly. Please confirm the same.

Comment: You can confirm it on your own by programming your suggested Turing machine and running it on some inputs.

Comment: I don't know how to program a Turing machine, I know only the theory part..

Comment: If you know how a Turing machine works and you know how to program, then you should be able to program a Turing machine.

Comment: You say you "ran [Sipser's] machine for a few strings" so why can't you do the same with your version?

Comment: I did it, then i only reached to this conclusion that this Turing Machine will also work without transition for 0 and 1 on state q6. as this machine is given in a standard book, i only want someone to confirm  what i am thinking is correct or i am missing something.